# Timeout on HttpClient / HttpClientHandler With Proxy

Tags: c#, http, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am scraping a site that requires the use of hundreds / thousands of proxies to make it through. I have a list of 20,000 proxies, but many are dead. When I encounter a dead proxy, I mark it and retry using a different one, but often times the timeout is around 15 seconds for a dead proxy.

I have tried setting the `Timeout` property, but that only seems to affect the actual HTTP request AFTER it has connected to the proxy server. While I have looked at dozens of pages, none I saw handled timing out the proxy, just the `HttpClient` request.

How can I set up a request that times out the proxy faster so I can move on to the next?

```
foreach(var proxy in proxies){
        var prox = new WebProxy($"{proxy.ip}:{proxy.port}");
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = prox, UseProxy = true };
        var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        try{
        var res = await client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com");
            //success, do something
            break;
        }catch{
            //failure, mark and try again
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using Stopwatch:

```
var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
    var resultTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com");
    while (timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds <= 2 && !resultTask.IsCompleted)
        await Task.Delay(100);

    if (!resultTask.IsCompleted)
        throw new Exception();

    string reply = resultTask.Result;
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach with `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var prox = new WebProxy($"{proxy.ip}:{proxy.port}");
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = prox, UseProxy = true };
var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
try
{
    var res = await client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com", source.Token);
    //success, do something
    break;
}
catch
{
    //failure or TaskCanceledException
}
```